# React Native - hide parent stack's header on screen located in child stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, header

I have main navigation stack with few child stacks. In `OnboardingStack` child stack, I set up custom header per screen, but it renders double header (adds one more header with child stack name above custom header intended for that screen). How can I get rid of it? Tried passing `screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}` on parent stack and then both headers hide (i.e. missing custom header on screen too). How can I get rid of that additional header above custom one?

```
const MainNavigation = () => {
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator id={'MainStack'}>
            <Stack.Screen
                name="SplashScreen"
                component={Splash}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={OnboardingStack} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthStack} />
            <Stack.Screen
                name="Home"
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
                component={Tabs}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
);
```

};

This is `OnboardingStack` :

```
const OnboardingStack = () => {
return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Onboarding">
        <Stack.Screen
            name="OnboardingStep1"
            component={OnboardingStep1}
            options={{
                header: () => <Header title={'header'} />,
            }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="OnboardingStep2"
            component={OnboardingStep2}
            options={{
                header: () => <Header title={'header'} />,
            }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="OnboardingStep3"
            component={OnboardingStep3}
            options={{
                headerShown: false,
            }}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

};

I want get rid of light gray header above my custom one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `options={{ headerShown: false }}` to this line in MainNavigation:

```
 <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={OnboardingStack} />
```

screenOptions prop is for a group or navigator while options prop is for a screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse options in `onBoarding` Stack also at initial place:

Follow like this :

```
const OnboardingStack = () => {
return (
    <Stack.Navigator options={{ headerShown: false }} initialRouteName="Onboarding">
        <Stack.Screen
            name="OnboardingStep1"
            component={OnboardingStep1}
            options={{
                header: () => <Header title={'header'} />,
            }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="OnboardingStep2"
            component={OnboardingStep2}
            options={{
                header: () => <Header title={'header'} />,
            }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="OnboardingStep3"
            component={OnboardingStep3}
            options={{
                headerShown: false,
            }}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
);
}
```